# Sort by datetime in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, datetime, dictionary

Looking for help on how to sort a python3 dictonary by a datetime object (as shown below, a value in the dictionary) using the timestamp below.

```
datetime: "2018-05-08T14:06:54-04:00"
```

Any help would be appreciated, spent a bit of time on this and know that to create the object I can do:

```
format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
# Make strptime obj from string minus the crap at the end
strpTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts[:-6], format)
# Create string of the pieces I want from obj
convertedTime = strpTime.strftime("%B %d %Y, %-I:%m %p")
```

But I'm unsure how to go about comparing that to the other values where it accounts for both day and time correctly, and cleanly.

Again, any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What does the dictionary look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datetime instances support the usual ordering operators (`<` etc), so you should order in the datetime domain directly, not with strings.

Use a callable to convert your strings to *timezone-aware* datetime instances:

```
from datetime import datetime

def key(s):
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
    s = ''.join(s.rsplit(':', 1))  # remove colon from offset
    return datetime.strptime(s, fmt)
```

This key func can be used to correctly sort values:

```
>>> data = {'s1': "2018-05-08T14:06:54-04:00", 's2': "2018-05-08T14:05:54-04:00"}
>>> sorted(data.values(), key=key)
['2018-05-08T14:05:54-04:00', '2018-05-08T14:06:54-04:00']
>>> sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: key(item[1]))
[('s2', '2018-05-08T14:05:54-04:00'), ('s1', '2018-05-08T14:06:54-04:00')]
```